# Kendo ui Grid two fields per column and row on insert

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-treeview

I really don´t know if this is possible or not, but it is something that i´ve been searching and not having any kind of luck.

I will try to explain my issue, normally when we have a grid and when we insert a new record, it always inserts one row and we have a input per column. What i want is to be able to insert a row BUT in a certain column instead of just showing one field, it appears TWO fields for the user to type, something like this:

```
ColumnTitle1 | ColumnTitle2 | ColumnTitle3
   Input         input           input
                                 input
```

at the end, what you see is just one row, but in the column3 it has two inputs, i have search about the row template, and even tried to do some "stuff" but it´s not worthy of showing because it didn´t work...is this even possible?!?!

Thanks for you time
Regards.

Comment: check custom column editor: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.editor

Comment: Thanks, i´ll check it out.